# What is the correct script path when serving static files with node express?

Tags: node.js, express, filepath, static-files

I always have problems finding the right path for the scripts and it must be because of the way i serve static files as my path is correct. In my code, I am trying to include materialize framework but its not being found and I don't understand why. I serve up my files in /browser

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../browser')));
```

from browser/index.html I use (as I believe) the right path, but its not working. Any help would be awesome so I don't keep making the same mistakes! Thank you very much!

flights/server/app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var morgan = require('morgan');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var app = express();
    module.exports = app;
    app.use(morgan('dev'));


    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../browser')));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log('Server is listening on port 1337!');
    });
```

flights/browser/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../materialize/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="flight.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        The content of the document......
    </body>
    </html>
```

my structure:

```
flights
   browser
      index.html
      flights.js
   server
      app.js
   css
     style.css
   materialize
      css
         materialize.min.css
      fonts
      js
         materialize.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing to understand that you need to place all your static files like css, js in a folder which can have sub folders for css and js and other things respectively.

Your structure should be single folder like public in your root project directory and then inside that public folder put the folders of css, js and other things.

Also this line

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../browser')));
```

Is not entirely correct. Use something like this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

public is the folder containing all the static files

Now assuming that you put a folder of materialize in your css folder which contains some materialise.css file then the URL will be something like
    http://localhost:3000/css/materialize/materialise.css

Also check out [express static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thank you! so when I put materialize folder into public folder and serve all files from public folder, materialize is being found. But I try to understand about the path as I don't want to put all files into the same folder. I left my js file insight the browser folder. I now serve all files from public folder AND from browser (added app.use(express.static('browser')) ) then insight my flights/public/index.html file I have the path to my js file: '../browser/flights.js'. It doesn't work. Could you please explain why?path is correct + I serve the files insight the browser folder.Thanks!!

Comment: Static file are not referenced like you you normally do in your html CSS project. When you use express.static('browser') it would set this folder as root path and if you want to access a file like browser/index.js then it would just be http://localhost:3000/index.js as explained above if you want to give path of a file that is in static just put the path `index.js` and it will be converted to http://localhost:3000/index.js

Comment: Im not sure if I understand you right. If I serve my files from browser, then the path to lets say index.js (from public/index.html) would not be browser/index.js but only index.js since Im serving all files insight browser. Is that correct? Also, how can I 'access' other files from my index.html file? For example if I npm install modules, I have to access them from my index.html. Do I also have to serve all node modules in my server/app.js file or can I not serve them and still access them from index.html? Thanks so much for answering and helping!!

Comment: In express.static whatever path you put will act as root and after that you have to access every other thing relative to root. Suppose you put a directory named X in express.static so X will be act as root. Then whatever is inside X you can give relative path to it. So on local system `X/index.html` will be referenced as localhost:3000/index.html but `X/somefolder/index.html` will be referenced as localhost:3000/somefolder/index.html. there is nothing special about node modules you can reference them as a described above in the comment.

Comment: so then I first have to add app.use(express.static('node_modules')) since they are not in my public folder but in flights/node_modules. Then from index.html which is in flights/public/index.html it would be (lets say for jQuery) 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' =a relative path? That and all other path combinations I tried don't work.

Comment: I would suggest put your npm dependencies also in public folder because they are also static files and it's pretty standard for any project. Then refer them with relative path

Comment: But what would I do if I wouldn't put them in the public folder? I really don't want to put everything into the same folder and try to understand the path when it comes to static files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149252/discussion-between-arpit-solanki-and-javascripting).